# levelplot plots the wrong categorical colours

Tags: r, qml, r-raster, levelplot, rastervis

I have received a .tif file alongside a .qml file containing information about the colour for each value (e.g. forest is green, clouds are black).

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

sm <- raster("UT_classification_coded.tif")

########## Classify raster / build attribute table
    sm <- ratify(sm)
    rat_sm <-levels(sm)[[1]]
    # Create categories
    rat_sm$landcover <- c('Forest', 'Active vegetation', 'Senescent vegetation', 'Disturbed', 'Rice flooded', 'Rice growing', 'Settlement', 'Water', 'Cloud', 'Cloud shadow', 'Forest') 
    levels(sm) <- rat_sm




##### plot the colours using the .qml file
     levelplot(sm, col.regions=c("#00b144", "#00ff00", "#ffc0a0", "#00ebeb", "#86b1ec", "#de57ff", "#ffff00", "#0000ff", "#000000", "#000000", "#008000"), xlab=NULL, ylab=NULL, scales=list(draw=FALSE), maxpixels=6e6)
```

The problem is that `levelplot` "believes" that the land use categories (Forest, rice flooded etc.) are in the reverse alphabetical order, and so are the colours. Thus the colours are assigned to the wrong category. For example, the last three colours ("#000000", "#000000", "#008000") are assigned to the Water, Settlement, Scenecent vegetation.

Grateful for any suggestions on a way to fix this (aside from plotting the colours in the reverse alphabetical order, which is tedious because that's not how the .qml file presents the information).

EDIT: here's the description of the .tif file

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 10981, 10981, 120582361  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent      : 299993, 409803, 9190235, 9300045  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=18 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:\Users\Documents\UT_classification_coded.tif 
names       : UT_classification_coded 
values      : 1, 15  (min, max)
```

Comment: See also: https://github.com/oscarperpinan/rastervis/issues/26#issuecomment-335011814

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have committed [changes in the code](https://github.com/oscarperpinan/rastervis/commit/1eed8f1c23562d2d4a49169406a4c3972dea1313#diff-012a5229c14990507bf74eb5c2ecbec0) to solve this issue. Please, try the development version of the package:

```
## install.packages('remotes')
remotes::install_github('oscarperpinan/rasterVis')
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked much better. A last observation: the legend of the plot is such that the first values of the legend are the last values assigned in ` rat_sm$landcover` (i.e. their display is still reversed from the  `rat_sm$landcover` vector)